# No JDBC Driver class was specified by property hibernate.connection.driver_class

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

With this Pom.xml:

```
<!-- Hibernate resources -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And With this context xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org     /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->



<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/x" />
    <property name="user" value="x" />
    <property name="password" value="x" />

       <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1800" />

</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="src.com.x.model.entities"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <!-- configuration pool via c3p0 -->                
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">600</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />
```

after im starting my server i get the following exception:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider - HHH000148: No JDBC Driver class was specified by property hibernate.connection.driver_class
WARN : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@724ccdfe -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
WARN : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@724ccdfe -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
```

what am i doing wrong here?
I'm using spring 3 and hibernate 4,
unfortunately i couldn't find this exact same error message in Google so i guess that means trouble

thanks!

Comment: hi. if you are getting APPARENT DEADLOCKs you are also getting lots of debugging information that you haven't included. please include the dump of active and panding tasks + active task stack traces. also, please specify what version of c3p0 you are using. if you can, show your DataSource config as it was dumped into your logs at INFO upon pool initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix these versions.  Use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

or even better:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernateOrmVersion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernateOrmVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

and define `hibernateOrmVersion` as a POM property